# Chrome for Android - Auto-refresh Causes Inaccurate Analytics, Wasted Resources, and More

Tags: google-chrome, android

So I need a way to suppress the auto refresh feature for mobile Chrome on Android (or any other browsers that act that way).

If you are not aware, mobile Chrome has a tendency to constantly refresh the page when going between apps and things. This causes all sorts of issues for the user, the network, the OP, the analytics, and the server.

From a usability perspective the auto-refresh feature baked in is highly annoying, especially on slower networks. It not only wastes your time waiting for the page to reload, but it wastes your data unnecessarily. It also causes extra load, inaccurate analytics, and loss of "state" sometimes.

Is there anything else I can do with responses, headers, caching, meta, etcetc to suppress this annoying behavior? It seems there is no solid answer, even from the client side.

Comment: Do you have another reference of this "auto-refresh" behaviour? To be honest, this is something I have not experienced.

Comment: @w3dk Not really any reference besides the hordes of forum posts and google product forum discussions about how to turn it off on the client side. Just imagine every time you switched windows/apps and came back, your tab refreshes. I guess its "memory related" but for real, i have enough mem to keep a browser state, its annoying default behavior. Example: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/2vrl9g/disable_autorefresh_on_chrome_android/ Another one: http://androidforums.com/threads/browser-auto-refresh-wasting-my-data.816738/ -- in all cases it seems hit or miss, like some people dunno